# Mysterious connection between homotopy and cohomotopy groups in small dimensions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology

Let $X$ be a CW-complex.

**Fact 0**. If $\pi_0(X) = 0$, then  $[X, S^0]$ is trivial.

*Proof.* If $X$ is path-connected, then it is connected, hence any map form $X$ to $S^0$ is just constant.

**Fact 1.** If $\pi_1(X) = 1$, then $[X, S^1]$ is trivial.

*Proof.* Indeed, the elements of $[X, S^1]$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$. If $X$ is simply connected, then its first Betti number vanishes.

The expectable  **Fact 2** fails to be true: the 3-dimensional sphere is $2$-connected, though the Hopf fibration gives a non-contractable map from $S^3$ to $S^2$.

Nevertheless, I refuse to believe that the fist two facts are just a coincidence and suspect that this is a degeneration of some more general fact (perhaps, a well-known).

Are there any considerations, what it could be?

UPD: As it was pointed out by Dylan Wilson and Chris Shommer-Pries, there is an obvious way to generalize  the **Fact 1** as  the equality $H^n(X, A) = [X, K(A, n)].$ However, the **Fact 0** could not be explained in the same way.

It seems that the 0-dimensional case is likely to be a simple coincedence. I have no idea about it, but I still wonder, if there is another general consideration which will give us both **Fact 0** and **Fact 1** as the particular cases.

Comment: I think the homotopy is a red herring, since in both cases you really use the (co)homology of X. The key fact about S^0 and S^1 that stops being true is that these particular spheres have no higher homotopy. With these considerations I'd say the 'general fact' is 'obstruction theory' which says we can study homotopy classes of maps via the cohomology of the source and the homotopy of the target.

Comment: Adding to Dylan's comment, the sequence of target spaces should probably have been $S^0$, $S^1= K(\mathbb{Z},1)$, $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$, $K(\mathbb{Z},3)$, etc. Then the "expected fact" is just the Hurewicz theorem.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries,

I was also thinking so, but $S^0 \neq K(\mathbb{Z}, 0)$. May be you are right, but I wonder if there is something more inside...

Comment: But $S^0\subset\mathbb{Z}=K(\mathbb Z,0)$, and $[X,S^0]$ is trivial if and only if $[X,\mathbb Z]$ is trivial.

Comment: In response to your edit: S^0 is K(Z/2, 0). Maybe you could say more about what you hope a generalization would look like?